# surjectivity and injectivity of the following function

Tags: analysis

I am trying to prove that given a function $f: \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x,y) = x + y\sqrt{n}$ for some fixed n not a perfect square, it is surjective and injective. I know that it is injective. As for surjectivity, I don't know what to show? I do know the function is defined uniquely on $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, since given $s = x + y\sqrt{n} \in \mathbb{R}$, $s$ is uniquely determined by $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ but that doesn't seem like a proof. Also what would be the cardinality of $B =\{x+y\sqrt{n}: x,y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$? I know that if $f$ is surjective and injective then it is bijective and thus it is countable. But im not sure whether its finite or $\aleph_0$. I guessing since $|\mathbb{Q}| = \aleph_0$, we can define bijection from $B \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Im sorry im not familiar with algebraic numbers. Why does $f(x,y)$ being an algebraic number imply that $f$ is not surjective?

Comment: @MartinR yeah I fixed the statement

Comment: @MartinR but if $|B| \leq |\mathbb{R}|$ wouldn't that imply there exists a surjective map between them? (that's from a theorem) or does that not hold when we talk about maps between countable and uncountable sets?

Comment: @MartinR I understood the first and last argument since im familiar with it. Currently im reading about transcendental numbers. Thank you for such a well explained answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct that $f$ is injective if $n$ is not a perfect square. The reason is that for integers $n$, $\sqrt n$ is either an integer or an *irrational* number.

But $f$ is not surjective. Here are three possible arguments, there are probably more:

- $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ is countable (as the cartesian product of a countable set with itself). If $f$ were bijective then $\Bbb R$ would be countable as well. But it is well-known that this is not the case, e.g. from [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).
- $f(x, y) = r$ implies $(r-x)^2 - n^2 y = 0$, i.e. $r$ is the solution of a polynomial with rational coefficients, that is an [algebraic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number). It follows that $f(x, y) =r$ has no solution in $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ if $r$ is a [transcendental number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number). There are *many* transcendental real numbers, $\pi$ and $e$ are well-known examples.
- If $m$ is an integer which is not a perfect square, and $m/n$ is not a perfect square, then $x+y \sqrt n = \sqrt m$ has no solution with integers $x, y$, i.e. $\sqrt m$ is not in the range of $f$.